# Expanding Linux Partition

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, hard-disk

I am running ubuntu 14 on my laptop, the laptop is normally windows 8 but it is dual booted with ubuntu. My ubuntu partition is 50gb and I know that I have 500gb free space which is wasted on my windows partition. I was wondering if anyone has experience or has found a good article explaining this. I have found a few but most are for windows 7 and ubuntu or xp and ubuntu. Windows 8 changed a lot of things and it gets confusing trying to look at a windows 7 guide.

Comment: Is the 500GB of free space in the Windows partition or is it unpartitioned space?

Comment: Nevermind.  You said it's in the Windows partition

Comment: you should show a screenshot of partitions from disks program

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72344/how-can-i-resize-ntfs-partition-in-gparted

Answer (score 0):

This can be trivially accomplished with `gparted`. Burn a DVD (or use an USB stick) with any distro that has a live CD (like any version of ubuntu), and boot using it.

When you have loaded your system from the DVD/USB, you will be able to run gparted (you can type `gparted` in a console, or type it in the window that shows up with CTRL+F2). From `gparted` you will be able to resize your partitions. It is as simple as dragging a bar.

Here is a screenshot of how `gparted` looks like:

[image: gparted]
<sub>(source: [gparted.org](http://gparted.org/screens/gparted-main-window.png))</sub>

There you can see the third button from left to right `Rezise/Move`. Just select your partition and click there.

I would recommend to defragment your Windows partition due to the awful FS that Windows use.

Comment: dont mind your answer is pretty vague, you should add steps, for this if you need some information you should ask it from the OP

Comment: IDK if it is that vague, as he has an Ubuntu partition, I'm assuming he knows how to boot from a live CD, and `gparted` is a graphical tool which is quite easy to use, there is a "resize partition" (or something like this) button there, it can't get easier than that. But I'll add more information if needed. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I will be trying this out soon and will post a comment if I am uncertain of anything. I am not sure if I should do this, or backup my windows partition for the data I have saved there then just format the whole thing for ubuntu

Comment: From my experience, it is rare to trash your Windows partition if you defrag it first, but it may indeed happen, so the safest is to backup before doing anything, just to be sure.